# utf-8 strings in program memory (__flash)

Tags: c, string, unicode, embedded, avr

i am trying to read and print unicode strings (Greek) in a avr from program memory,
I am using the __flash atribute but my strings come out corrupted. ex: instead of ΧΡΗΣΤΗ I get ΧΡΤ⸮⸮, english seems to work somehow.

This is the way I did it:

in  Print_menu_file.c:

```
static const __flash char * const __flash *Unicode_text;

const __flash char * const __flash Greek_text[35]=
{
    (const __flash char[40]) { "ΜΕΝΟΥ ΧΡΗΣΤΗ"     }, //USER_MENU
    (const __flash char[]) { "ΡΥΘΜΙΣΗ ΗΜΕΡ/ΩΡΑΣ" }, //SET_DATE_TIME
    (const __flash char[]) { "ΠΡΟΒ. ΑΙΣΘΗΤΗΡΩΝ"  }, //SHOW_SENSRORS
    (const __flash char[]) { "ΘΕΡΜΟΚΡΑΣ. 1/2"    }, //TEMP_1_OF_2
}

void Print_string(void)
{
 char* string=0;
 Unicode_text=Greek_text;
 strcpy_P(string,Unicode_text[1]);

 lcd_print_unicode(string);
}
```

Comment: You're passing the value of an an uninitialized variable (`string`) to `strcpy_P`. You didn't show `Unicode_text` being initialized before its use either.

Comment: I fixed the string init, still no joy "Unicode_text=Greek_text" goes before strcpy, I will edit this now

Comment: Does `strcpy_P(0, Unicode_text[1])` aka `strcpy_P(NULL, Unicode_text[1])` really make sense to you?

Comment: /** \ingroup avr_pgmspace
    \fn char *strcpy_P(char *dest, const char *src)
well, since "string" is the destination pointer, it does

Comment: You know how `x = 2; y = x + 3;` could also be written as `y = 2 + 3;`. Well, `string = 0; strcpy_P(string, Unicode_text[1])` is the same thing as `strcpy_P(0, Unicode_text[1])`. You aren't passing `string`; the concept of passing a variable isn't even a thing. The pointer being passed is the one stored in `string`, which is `0` aka `NULL`, which isn't a valid destination pointer. You are doing `strcpy_P(0, Unicode_text[1])` aka `strcpy_P(NULL, Unicode_text[1])`, which makes no sense.

Comment: @Spitfire1.2 _string_ is as you say the _pointer_ to the destination, not the destination itself.  It points to _nowhere_.   Also strcpy_P is not defined for UTF-8.  Use memcpy_P() perhaps? By

Answer (score 0):

As in ikegami's comment suggests, your problem lies in this code:

```
void Print_string(void)
{
 /////problem below//////
 char* string=0;
 /////problem above/////

 Unicode_text=Greek_text;
 strcpy_P(string,Unicode_text[1]);

 lcd_print_unicode(string);
}
```

You have a pointer to a character buffer pointing at 0.   Now, 0 MIGHT be an allocated buffer for your destination strcopy, but most likely its not (it's probably the vector table).

`strcpy_P` does not allocate a buffer for you.  It only writes to a buffer who's pointer you've provided.

Make

```
char * string=0;
```

into

```
char string[MAX_EXPECTED_STRING_LENGTH_PLUS_TERMINATING_0];
```

and your problem will be fixed.

Comment: AVR is a Harvard architecture, and code always runs from Flash which cannot be written by a normal memory access like the one `strcpy_P` uses for writing to its destination. So code address 0 is in Flash and is where the vector table usually lives. However, `strcpy_P(0, ...)` will write the string to data address 0. This will overwrite whatever data happens to be stored at data address 0, and parts of that data might then be overwritten by `strcpy_P` or `lcd_print_unicode()` before `lcd_print_unicode()` actually reads from the string bytes following address 0.